# excel vba apply formula for all cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macros. I have few routine works which I can automate using macros. First step is to apply clean formula for all cells (entire sheet). I tried recording macro option. It works for only one file. I am unable to determine range function for entire data. Any idea or suggestion is appreciable.

How can I change the number below one

```
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=CLEAN(Sheet1!RC:R[54234]C[21])"
```

Below is sample code.

```
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=CLEAN(Sheet1!C.End(xlDown))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select the range in order to address it. The following formula will do.

```
    Range("A1").Formula2R1C1 = "=CLEAN(Sheet1!C1:C" & Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).End(xlDown).Row & ")"
```

You may use `Range("C3")` in place of `Cells(3, 1)` if you prefer. However, if you expect to copy everything in the referenced column C then this line will do the same job.

```
Range("A1").Formula2R1C1 = "=CLEAN(Sheet1!C:C)"
```

There doesn't seem to be a good reason for using `FormulaR1C1` here in place of the plain `Formula` property. Moreover, neither of the above formulas copied the entire range for me reliably because Excel inserts the spill-preventer `@` into the formula most of the time. Therefore I recommend the indirect use of `CLEAN()` and paste values to the new sheet that are already "cleaned".